# How common is Apache webserver Filesmatch configuration ".+\.ph(p([3457s]|\-s)?|t|tml)"

Tags: php, apache

The OWASP website has a page about [Insecure File Uploads](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Unrestricted_File_Upload) which talks about an insecure Apache filesmatch directive:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p([3457s]|\-s)?|t|tml)">  
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php  
</FileMatch>
```

I wonder where that example configuration comes from if it's a common one or just a bypass-able configuration. Searching for it online mostly turns up pages about setting up and bypassing it.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out what was wrong with that regex. It's the missing end-of-string anchor. So it would match to `foo.phpx`

Comment: Yes, I think it also allows a variety of other examples like `foo.php.gif`.